# Pass array to an component/function as input

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function

I set up an component which look like:

```
ImageWaterFall.js:
export default ({ images = [], style }) => (
 <View style={[styles.container, style]}>
  {images.map((image, index) => (
    <View key={index}>
      <Image style={{ width: Width, height: Height }} source={{ uri: image }} />
    </View>
  ))}
</View> 
);
```

And here's my invoker component:

```
const images = [
  "XXXX_A.jpg",
  "XXXX_B.jpg",
];
export default class XX extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageWaterFall {images}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I will give an Error, says unexpected token. I'm wondering how should I pass an array into a component(func) like above?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual text and line number of the error message.

Comment: Have you tried `<ImageWaterFall images={images}/>` to begin with?

Comment: The error msg says:"XXXX expected ...". So I correct it to <ImageWaterFall {...images}/> as a result, the function will only get an object instead of an array, and nothing won't be rendered.